# R: How to unzip a .zipx file

Tags: r, unzip

I'm trying to unzip a .zipx file using the unzip function in R and I keep getting an error that the zip file is corrupt. I can unzip the contents of this file using 7zip so I know the file isn't corrupt and when I use `list=TRUE` in the code below I can see the contents of the zip file - suggesting to me that it isn't corrupt.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
 setwd("C:\\Test\\zip")

i="RD_01_01_2015.zipx"

unzip(i, files = NULL, list = FALSE, overwrite = TRUE,
      junkpaths = FALSE, exdir = "C:\\Test\\zip", unzip = "internal",
      setTimes = FALSE)
```

Comment: `?unzip`: _"The default internal method is a minimal implementation..."_  - maybe the format is not supported? Why not just use 7zip via command line (e.g. `?system`).

Comment: Hey that's a great idea, I managed to get it working that way. Thanks LukeA

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an R expert, but I do know that most utilities save files with a ZIPX extension when they use some of the more recent ZIP features and compression methods, which aren't supported by all unzip tools.

It sounds like your file is fine, but R doesn't implement all the necessary features to unpack it and 7-Zip does.